# How to map different many to manys with same constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, constraints, data-integrity

I have a data model that i have some concerns over.  Here it is:

[image]

My concern is that it's possible to assign an application to a member, and then assign a role that is from a different application to the member.

Now, I know I can put a constraint on this to ensure that doesn't happen, but that seems like a bandaid.  I would rather design the model so that a constraint was not required.

Can anyone suggest how to alter the model to ensure that a member can only be assigned roles from an application it is assigned to?

Comment: Are you saying, that a member can only be assigned to a single application? Or that the member needs to have a single role per application…?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with a constraint in your scenario.  Any fix I can think of would require some ugly de-normalization...

Comment: Seems to me that the model is fine.  What you're wanting to accomplish sounds more like business logic/application level validation.  Your application should enforce the integrity by traversing the relationships.  If you want to prevent your application from doing it from the database side, you'd be looking into wrapping it with a procedure most likely.

Comment: @Mystere Man, per your business rules, can a Member be assigned to an Application yet not be assigned to a Role that is assigned to that Application?

Comment: @TimLehner - No, a user must be assigned to at least one application, and at least one role from that application.  They can be assigned to many applications, and assigned to roles from any of those applications.  They cannot be assigned to roles from applications they are not assigned to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you run into this kind of problem when you've split a key. Fixing that split key, then using overlapping foreign key constraints is usually what you're looking for.

```
create table cmember (
  cmemberid integer primary key,
  username varchar(15) not null,
  emailaddress varchar(64) not null
);

create table application (
  applicationid integer primary key,
  description varchar(50) not null
);

create table member_application (
  cmemberid integer not null references cmember (cmemberid),
  applicationid integer not null references application (applicationid),
  primary key (cmemberid, applicationid)
);

create table role (
  roleid integer primary key,
  rolename varchar(25) not null
);

create table crole (
  croleid integer not null references role (roleid),
  -- Include the application id in this table . . .
  applicationid integer not null references application (applicationid),
  -- and make it part of the primary key.
  primary key (croleid, applicationid)
);

create table member_role (
  cmemberid integer not null references cmember (cmemberid),
  croleid integer not null,
  applicationid integer not null,
  primary key (cmemberid, croleid, applicationid),
  -- Note the overlapping foreign key constraints.
  foreign key (croleid, applicationid) references crole (croleid, applicationid),
  foreign key (cmemberid, applicationid) references member_application (cmemberid, applicationid)
);

insert into cmember values (1, 'A', 'A@b.com');
insert into cmember values (2, 'B', 'B@b.com');

insert into application values (1, 'App 1');
insert into application values (2, 'App 2');

insert into member_application values (1, 1);
insert into member_application values (2, 2);

insert into role values (1, 'Admin');

insert into crole values (1, 1);
insert into crole values (1, 2);

insert into member_role values (1, 1, 1);
insert into member_role values (2, 1, 2);
```

Member 1 is assigned only to application 1. So trying to insert a row that references application 2 should fail.

```
insert into member_role values (1,1,2);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "member_role" violates foreign key constraint "member_role_cmemberid_fkey1"
DETAIL:  Key (cmemberid, applicationid)=(1, 2) is not present in table "member_application".
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

the way is remove foreign key to `CMemberID` in `Member_Role` and create a foreign key in this table (Member_Role) to `Member_Application`. New foreign key must contains both fields: ApplicationID + CRoleID

Now:

```
Member_Role ( CMemberID , CROleID )
PK = CMemberID + CROleID
FK1 (to CMember) =  CMemberID
FK2 (to CRole) = CRoleId
```

Solution:

```
CRole: Create unique constraint on CRoleID + ApplicationID
Member_Application: create unique constraint on CMemberID + ApplicationID
Member_Role ( CMemberID , ApplicationID, CRoleID )
PK = CMemberID + ApplicationID + CRoleID
FK1 (to Member_Application) = CMemberID + ApplicationID
FK2 (to CRole) = ApplicationID + CRoleID
```

Comment: Seems like this would still allow for any Role to be connected to that Member Application

Comment: To connect a Role to a Member Application CRoleID and also ApplicationID must match. Both. With the last constraint only a application members can obtain application roles.